# How to derive Weierstrass factorization for $\cos(z)$ from $\tan(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8z}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4z^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

Given that: $\tan(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8z}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4z^2}$

Integrate on both sides:

$-\ln(\cos(z))=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \ln\left[ (2n+1)^2-4z^2 \right]+\ln c_n\right)$

Simplify:

$\cos(z)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty c_n \left[ (2n+1)^2-4z^2 \right]$

Determine $c_n$:

let $z=0$

$1=\prod_{n=0}^\infty c_n(2n+1)^2$

One choice (also, this is the correct choice) is:

$c_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

But how to show this choice is unique?

Comment: You really should only have one integration constant, which you can then set by $\cos0=1$. But that means it's more helpful to work with $\ln[1-4z^2/((2n+1)\pi)^2]$.

Comment: The integration is term by term, so for each term the integration constant could be different, so I put $c_n$ and $c_n$ is independent of $z$ @J.G.

Comment: I know what you did, but that's not how integration works. There just aren't that many degrees of freedom in specifying a periodic antiderivative of $\tan z$.

Comment: I see, thank you! @J.G.